# Creating a binary variable in R from a column of values

Tags: r, data-analysis, dummy-variable

I need to create a dummy variable from another variable that has 3 values.  The variable is TR,The values being Standard, Track_E, Non_standard.  I want a new variable that distinguishes that Track_E is given value 1, the rest are 0, which is combination of standard and non_standard

This is the code I have tried so far.

```
CPS2011_12HSOnly$TR=as.factor(CPS2011_12HSOnly$TR)   
CPS2011_12HSOnly$Yr_round <- ifelse(CPS2011_12HSOnly$TR == "Track_E", 1)
```

it gives the following error:

> Error in ifelse(CPS2011_12HSOnly$TR == "Track_E", 1) : 
>     argument "no" is missing, with no default

Comment: `CPS2011_12HSOnly$Yr_round <- as.integer(CPS2011_12HSOnly$TR == "Track_E")`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the error message `ifelse` is missing `no` argument. Check `?ifelse`.

So you need to do

```
CPS2011_12HSOnly$Yr_round <- ifelse(CPS2011_12HSOnly$TR == "Track_E", 1, 0)
```

However, you can also do this without `ifelse`

```
CPS2011_12HSOnly$Yr_round <- as.integer(CPS2011_12HSOnly$TR == "Track_E")
```

Comment: Thank you, I realized that as soon as I posted, but hopefully this helps someone in the future